# Append string while saving it to attribute and remove while calling it

Tags: swift, xcode

I like to add `"abc"` to `eventTextField.text` and save it to the attribute`eventName` below

```
eventInformation.setValue(eventTextField.text, forKey: "eventName")
```

I tried this

```
let abcString = "abc"
eventInformation.setValue(eventTextField.text?.append(abcString), forKey: "eventName")
```

but my app is crashing with following error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for
>   attribute: property = "eventName"; desired type = NSString; given type
>   = _SwiftValue; value = ().'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `append` is mutating but does not return anything,
that's the `_SwiftValue; value = ()` (Void)

You need an extra step:

```
let abcString = "abc"
eventTextField.text?.append(abcString)
eventInformation.setValue(eventTextField.text, forKey: "eventName")
```